# is possible : cast char to varchar while join table in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, casting

Can I cast `B1` `char(2)` which joins on `A1` `varchar2(2)` :

```
SELECT * FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B 
    ON CAST(B.B1 AS VARCHAR2(2)) = A.A1
```

It results to no errors, but there no data displayed.

Is the above query possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast it, but it isn't doing that you think, or seem to be relying on. Assuming you have a one-character value in the field you're joining on, you don't get a match, with or without the cast:

```
create table a (a1 varchar2(2));
create table b (b1 char(2));

insert into a values ('X');
insert into b values ('X');

select * from a left join b on b.b1 = a.a1;

A1 B1
-- --
X     

select * from a left join b on cast(b.b1 as varchar2(2)) = a.a1;

A1 B1
-- --
X
```

The cast is chaging the data type, but not the data; it is still blank-padded. The only difference is that it's done explicitly in the value, rather implicitly as you'd see with a `char`. You can verify that the value is the same with the `dump()` function:

```
select dump(b.b1) dump_char,
  dump(cast(b.b1 as varchar2(2))) dump_varchar2
from b;

DUMP_CHAR            DUMP_VARCHAR2      
-------------------- --------------------
Typ=96 Len=2: 88,32  Typ=1 Len=2: 88,32
```

So the type has changed, from 96 (`char`) to 1 (`varchar2`), but the value is the same. Compare that with your value in table A and you'll see they are not the same:

```
select dump(a.a1) dump_varchar2 from a;

DUMP_VARCHAR2      
--------------------
Typ=1 Len=1: 88
```

Your cast B value still has the trailing space, the A value does not, therefore they don't match. You can remove that trailing space for comparison with `trim()` or `rtrim()`:

```
select * from a left join b on rtrim(b.b1) = a.a1;

A1 B1
-- --
X  X
```

There is an implicit conversion from `char` to `varchar2` within the `rtrim()` call, so you could still cast that explicitly for clarity.

Note that this assumes you never have a trailing space in A. It may be safer to cast the other way:

```
select * from a left join b on b.b1 = cast(a.a1 as char(2));

A1 B1
-- --
X  X
```

... but which side you cast/trim will also affect which indexes can be used.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B 
    ON TRIM(B.B1) = A.A1
```

i prefer this syntax to the cast for purely aesthetic reasons, although presumably others exist